# How to prevent ViewPager from leaking RAM?

Tags: android

I have a simple ViewPager and FragmentStatePagerAdapter handling 7 fragments. These fragments contain LinearLayouts containing TextViews and ImageViews.
My ViewPager is set to keep only 2 fragments outside the screen (viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);).

What I observe: **When I swipe horizontally between fragments, the memory usage (observed using Android Profile) keeps on increasing.** Once I reach .8GB, the app will not draw any more ImageViews.

I was curious about this, so I added log output to OnCreate(), onCreateView(), OnAttach(), OnDetach(), OnDestroy(), and observed that they are all called at every swipe (as expected). When I exit the Activity the RAM usage remains high for a while, then starts going down after a few minutes.

I have no idea why the memory usage goes up. Here is the Fragment code:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    Log.e("ViewSchedule_Day", "OnAttach");
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.e("ViewSchedule_Day", "Oncreate");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mDay = getArguments().getInt(ARG_DAY);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.e("ViewSchedule_Day", "OncreateView");
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_schedule__day, container, false);
    return view;
}
```

Does something in the above cause this issue? If no, where else could be a good place to look?

EDIT: I ran some tests with empty fragments (onCreateView simply inflates the view, as shown in above code), the memory is still increasing every time I swipe between fragments.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are loading large images(large size). so check them. 
also this link might help you
[Graphics performance](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics)

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I'm loading little vector icons, but a large quantity (400). To prevent drawing everything at once, I use RecyclerView to only draw the ones seen by the user (about 40 icons).

I ran some test with empty fragments, still getting an increasing RAM usage. I'll update the question with this information.